# checkbox checked to show a form input field and after submitting form a mysql query is run at background

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, forms

I want to show a checkbox which styling I found from http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/.
Now I want to show a input form with just single text input. That will be submitted by cliking submitt button and the mysql query will be automatically run in background.

My javascript for checkbox is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('input:checkbox:not([safari])').checkbox();
            $('input[safari]:checkbox').checkbox({cls:'jquery-safari-checkbox'});
            $('input:radio').checkbox();
        });

        displayForm = function (elementId)
        {
            var content = [];
            $('#' + elementId + ' input').each(function(){
                var el = $(this);
                if ( (el.attr('type').toLowerCase() == 'radio'))
                {
                    if ( this.checked )
                        content.push([
                            '"', el.attr('name'), '": ',
                            'value="', ( this.value ), '"',
                            ( this.disabled ? ', disabled' : '' )
                        ].join(''));
                }
                else
                    content.push([
                        '"', el.attr('name'), '": ',
                        ( this.checked ? 'checked' : 'not checked' ), 
                        ( this.disabled ? ', disabled' : '' )
                    ].join(''));
            });
            alert(content.join('\n'));
        }

        changeStyle = function(skin)
        {
            jQuery('#myform :checkbox').checkbox((skin ? {cls: skin} : {}));
        }

    </script>
```

and my html is:

```
<form id="myform">
        <table cellspacing="5">
            <tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th>Last Name</th></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" /></td><td>Davolio</td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" class="top5" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" class="top5" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" class="top5" /></td><td>Peacock</td><td>Margaret</td><td>Sales Representative</td></tr>
            </table>
    </form>
```

My question is that from where should I start, and how to do this.

Comment: My first question would be, is that jQuery code you wrote, or code you copied and pasted and are now looking for us to modify to get it to work the way that you want? if that's the case, please make attempts on your own to get this working and show us what you have tried.

Comment: I think you should start from trying to do something! This way you're going to face errors and then you can come and ask them here. Simple.